# Vagrant java 1.6 to 1.8

Tags: java, ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrant-provision

I Installed **vagrant** on my machine with **hashicorp-precise32** virtual machine. It installed java 1.6 whereas i want **java 1.8**. Do i have to install another virtual machine? How to get java 1.8?

Comment: that image might have outdated version of Java, write a chef or other provisioner tool to get it upgraded to java 8 or create an image with Java8 and reuse it

Comment: The answers given build upon the [Ubuntu Personal Package Archive](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) (PPA) to obtain java 8. There is also a [gist with the Vagrant provision block](https://gist.github.com/tinkerware/cf0c47bb69bf42c2d740) based on that same PPA.

Comment: Consider upgrading to a 14.04 or 16.04 image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add below lines in your **Vagrantfile**, It will install `Java 8 (accepting licenses)` and also set the Environmental variables in your guest VM:

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
echo "Setting environment variables for Java 8.."
sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-set-default
```

Moreover, you can refer [Creating and Provisioning VM using Vagrant](http://www.dzone.com/articles/vagrant)

Comment: Thanks Arpit, it worked. But i am still getting java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError, Unsupported major.minor version 52.0. Is tomcat still picking up older version? Any idea?

Comment: Check your Tomcat , JAVA_HOME version or refer my article, you will get your answer.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is empty and default is 1.8 now. Also tomcat is picking up the default but still getting that exception. Btw where can i find your article? Sorry i am a newbie here.

Comment: You can login to Tomcat manager from host and check which version of JAVA, tomcat is picking and more you can refer: http://www.dzone.com/articles/vagrant

Comment: Your article was very helpful. Thanks a lot. I got it working. I build the war on VM using gradle and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the os you put on the virtualbox, the one you installed has ubuntu so you will want to follow instructions from [here](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Comment: It will install Java 8 but ask user to accept the permission and when you are working with Vagrant, you don't have control over it.

Comment: @Arpit start up a vagrant machine, ssh in, and run these commands. It installs it just fine.

Comment: If I want to create the VM from same vagrant file again, then again I need to install Java 8(If I need), correct?

Comment: @arpit yes if you want to move the vm to a different machine then yes, you will have to edit the vagrant file.